# How do I get posts from category using the slug?

Tags: wordpress

I have my own theme and I'd like to display posts on my home page from a specific category.

So far I've achieved it like this:

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 10, 'category' => 6 );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $posts as $post ): setup_postdata($post); 
?>

    <divs with the_title() the_excerpt() etc ></div>

<?php 
    endforeach; 
?>
```

But what if I want to get the category by a its slug? Or is it possible to simply make a category selection box in from within the admin panel?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Replace your *`category`* parameter with **`category_name`**

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 10, 'category_name' => 'cat-slug' );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $posts as $post ): setup_postdata($post); 
?>

<divs with the_title() the_excerpt() etc ></div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

For more info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters

Answer (score 4):

suppose you have category name 'ice cakes' and category slug as 'ice-cakes', then our code to retrieve post under category 'ice cakes' is as follows:

```
<?php
              $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 3,
               'category_name' => 'ice-cakes' );

              $icecakes = get_posts( $args );
              foreach ( $icecakes as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
                  <li>
                      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                  </li>
              <?php endforeach; 
              wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass slug in the `get_posts` method of WordPress
suppose your category slug is `ice-cake`

```
$args = array('numberposts' => 10, 'category' => 'ice-cake');
$posts = get_posts($args);
```

For more info : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/