# How to display all post from custom postype category?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to display posts from a single custom post type category. For example: I have custom post type: 'Cources' and three category of this post type: Course one, Cource two, Cource three. I need separately display all posts from this category.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
  $args = array (
  'post_type' => 'cource',
  'cat' => 5, // id one of category
);

 $cat_one = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php while ( $cat_one->have_posts() ) :  $cat_one->the_post(); ?>      
 <div class="widget_item">
    <figure style="background-image: url(<?=$url;?>)"></figure>
    <div class="widget_meta">
        <ul>
            <li class="widget_item_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
            <li><time><?php the_field('evente_date'); ?></time> 
            <li class="place"><?php the_field('evente_place'); ?> <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

And nothing happens. If I remove 'cat' => 5 All posts are displayed from a custom post type. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Didn't get you, What you exactly want ?

Comment: I need to display separately all posts from each custom post type category.

Comment: Are you using a custom taxonomy?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202245/how-do-i-get-posts-from-category-using-the-slug

Comment: Yes, I am using custom taxonomy.
Thanks for the link I am going try to use that advice now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the taxonomy parameters in your query:

```
$args = array (
  'post_type' => 'cource',
  'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'cource',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => 'yout-taxonomy-term-slug-here',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Docs: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: Thank you man you safe my time and my evening. This is such an obvious solution, but I could not understand the documentation.

Comment: Glad to help. The docs page on WP Query is super useful -https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query. In addition to the taxonomy query params I also reach for Meta query params frequently. Another nugget, any of the args arrays you put together for WP Query can also be passed to `get_posts()`, my preferred way of querying. Good luck!